# Finding center of a set of points to sort them clockwise?

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I want to sort a vector of points in clockwise order to form a polygon but I need the proper center to do so. I have tried the averages method, but a few of the points did not sort correctly at all. What is the correct way to find the center that will work when sorting points in a clockwise manner?

It is failing on the concave parts

Thanks

Here is a picture:
[image]

The green circle is the center.

It should look more like this:
[image]

Comment: Given that the polygon is just defined by its points and is non-convex, I am not sure there is a solution without some further constraints. It is not clear that the polygon is uniquely defined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The notion of "sorting in clockwise order" is not well-defined if you don't have a pre-defined center point.

If all you have is just a bunch of points that you need to sort and you don't know the center in advance, then the problem does not generally have a single solution. The problem has many alternative solutions, each of which will give you a different polygon as the result.

Moreover, finding a center that would allow you to re-create the original polygon by CW (or CCW) sorting is only possible for a special class of polygons: so called [star-shaped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-shaped_polygon) polygons. The main property of star-shaped polygon is that it is possible to find a point inside the polygon from which the entire interior of the polygon is "observable" (I hope it is clear without definition what "observable" means).

If your polygon is not star-shaped, then such center point simply does not exist. And, for this reason, it is not possible to re-create the original polygon by CW sorting.

Your cow contour in the picture is obviously not a star-shaped polygon, which means that you will never be able to re-create the original cow contour by sorting the points around some center, any center. There's no "correct way". It is not possible.

Comment: Then what sorts of algorithms would get me the original cow?

Comment: @Milo: Imagine a simpler polygon, such as a 5-pointed star. If you erase the lines and just look at the points, there are at least two possible reconstructions: a star, or two concentric pentagons with one missing side each, connected by two lines. Erasing the lines throws out valuable information and the problem cannot be reliably solved. (Coincidentally, as Andrey says, stars do happen to be amenable to the algorithm you already tried, but cows are not stars.)

Comment: @Milo: If the points on the contour are packed very densely (especially in curved portions), then you can recreate the cow by just jumping from one point to the next closest point. However, if the points are not sufficiently dense, then in some places you might end up with errors. In general case, it is simply not possible to re-create the original contour from an unordered set of points. As I said above, there are many different contours that can be built from a set of points. Since you have no way to decide, which one is the right one, you can't re-create it.

Comment: Picture 2 was created with a program called PhisicsEditor, how can they do it?

Comment: @Milo: Well, it is quite possible that your set of points possesses some important property, that allows one to recreate the original picture. You are simply not telling us what that property is (or you don't know it yourself). While PhisicsEditor knows that property and takes advantage of it. For example, it can do what I mentioned above: just jumps from one point to its closes neighbor.

Comment: PhisicsEditor can do it with any picture I throw at it. Anyhow, thanks for the info :)

Comment: @Milo: Any? What is it going to do if you give it just 5 points: 4 at each corner of a square and one in the center?

Comment: I suspect the reason [PhysicsEditor](http://www.physicseditor.de) can do it is because it is actually doing _the reverse_ - it uses edge detection to find a line around the edge of the shape, then adds vertices as appropriate to define that line. It _doesn't_ start with vertices and then create a line.

Comment: @Mac what sort of edge detection algorithm would be used for this sort of problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think the most reliable strategy (aside from redesigning your program/system so this problem doesn't arise in the first place) is to minimize the total perimeter of the polygon.

This isn't an easy problem, but here is a heuristic that should work well:

1. For each point, find the next closest point. This defines a set of potential connections.
2. Add the longest potential connection to the polygon.
3. Repeat 1-2, but ignore connections that have already been made and points that already have two connections.

This is only a heuristic, not a solution. I'm not sure that it's even guaranteed to produce a polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Taking *any* point as the center, you should be able to determine the distance and angle to all the points in the set, and sorting by angle is simple after that. However, the point that you choose as the center will influence the sort order, so it's hard to know what the "correct" order should be until you choose a point as the center.

So, if you chose the centroid as the center (seems like a good choice), but some points are sorted incorrectly relative to that point, then I'd say that there's a problem in your sorting code. Alternately, if you had an expectation about the sort order that wasn't met by your algorithm, then I'd say that one of your assumptions (sort order or center location) was incorrect.

Comment: See my pictures for more insight on the problem.

Comment: Your sorting is correct. The problem is that you can't produce the cow by sorting according to angle.

Comment: Then what sorts of algorithms could do this? Right now I just get the outline verticies from the picture itself but they are in scanline order.

Comment: Looks like you've got lots of points, so you might try starting with any point and drawing a line to the nearest neighbor. It's not perfect, but it should work for the cow.

Answer (score -1):

Refer [Barycenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid). May be this is what u r looking for